# How can I use SCANF with a pointer to an array?

Tags: c++, pointers

Write a program that accepts a C-string input from the user and reverses the contents of the string. Your program should work by using two pointers. The “head” pointer should be set to the address of the first character in the string, and the “tail” pointer should be set to the address of the last character in the string (i.e., the character before the terminating null). The program should swap the characters referenced by these pointers, increment “head” to point to the next character, decrement “tail” to point to the second-to-last character, and so on, until all characters have been swapped and the entire string reversed.
Expected behaviors:
Enter the input text
hello guys
syug olleh

This is the assignment quest.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char inp_str[50];
    char* hl;
    char *tl;
    cout<<"Enter string ";
    scanf("%s",inp_str);
    hl=&inp_str[0];
    tl=strchr(inp_str,'\0')-1;
    for (hl; hl <= tl; hl++){
        for(tl;tl>= hl;tl--) {
            char temp_val;
            temp_val=*hl;
            *hl=*tl;
            *tl=temp_val;
        }
    }
    cout<<inp_str;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting an error

```
"expression result unused [-Wunused-value]" for tl in for(tl;tl>= hl;tl--) and hl in for (hl; hl <= tl; hl++).
```

Comment: Uh - why do you want to use scanf() and character arrays in a C++ program????  If you insist on doing so, the correct syntax would be `scanf("%s",inp_str);` (without the & addressof operator).

Comment: _@Nourhan Berjawi_ Do not vandalize your question in a way that makes the answer worthless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array name is the pointer to the (first element of the) array.

```
scanf("%s", inp_str);
```

Your main error is that you've used two loops where you should have only used one

Not

```
for (hl; hl <= tl; hl++){
    for(tl;tl>= hl;tl--)
{
    char temp_val;
    temp_val=*hl;
    *hl=*tl;
    *tl=temp_val;
}
}
```

but

```
for (; hl <= tl; hl++, tl--)
{
    char temp_val;
    temp_val=*hl;
    *hl=*tl;
    *tl=temp_val;
}
```

Think about the process of reversing a string, does that process need nested loops, or does it just need one loop?

Your compiler errors occur because you used `h1` and `t1` in the first expression in your for loops. The result of those expressions are unused (hence the error), just leave them out, as in my example.

PS haven't checked the code very much, so it might not be correct even with the changes suggested above.